# dict KeyError for a key that is already inside the dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dict whose keys are a bunch of numpy.datetime64 elements. However, when I'm trying to access a key that is already inside the dict, a KeyError Exception pops out.

```py
a = np.datetime64('2018-12-28T00:00:00.000000')
result[a]
```

This gives an error

```py
sorted(result.keys())[-113]  == a

result[[i for i in result.keys() if i == a][0]]
```

While this gives the value that I want

Comment: @Vishnudev No, keys of a `dict` can be any kind of object, as long as it is hashable.

Comment: Sorry, I commented just after your original comment (PS: don't delete comments if not necessary, as it can be confusing)... As I already said, any kind of object can be a key of a `dict`, even if it's not immutable (for example, a subclassed list, which *shouldn't* be immutable, but you can add your own __hash__ implementation).

That said, @Zhiao, please provide us a [minimal, Reroducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can help you with.